# Trying to print up down arrow keys

Tags: terminal, escape-characters

I have this:

I read down arrow key

```
abc@abc-ubuntu:~/bashpratice$ read -n 3 key
^[[Babc@abc-ubuntu:~/bashpratice$
```

I am able to grep for it

```
abc@abc-ubuntu:~/bashpratice$ echo $key | grep '\['
[B
abc@abc-ubuntu:~/bashpratice$ echo $key | grep '\[B'
[B
```

But echoing the key just prints spaces

```
abc@abc-ubuntu:~/bashpratice$ echo $key

abc@abc-ubuntu:~/bashpratice$
```

Why does echoing the key just give spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What happens when downarrow is typed in a terminal

As reported by `xxd -p`, when typing <kbd>↓</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> :

```
xxd -p
^[[B
1b5b420a
```

The downarrow key leads to a sequence of 3 characters:

- the first is `\x1b` (a.k.a. escape, see `man ascii`), echoed on the terminal as `^[`,
- second is `\x5b`, that is `[`,
- third is `\x42`, that is `B`.

The last character, `\x0a` is just the newline character.

So, downarrow is echoed on the terminal as `^[[B`. In reality, this corresponds to the `1b5b42` hex sequence, which is the one actually sent to the reading process.

#### About your experiments

Your `key` variable contains the `1b5b42` hex sequence. Check it with

```
echo -n "$key" | xxd -p
1b5b42
```

Of course, `grep` will be able to catch the `5b42` hex sequence (that is `[B`)¹.

However, when you send something to the terminal, the escape character `\x1b` is interpreted as the beginning of some special escape sequence. For example `\x1b[31m` is a sequence that is recognized by most terminals and means "use red foreground color". Check it yourself:

```
echo -e 'hello \x1b[31myou'
```

The sequence will change the current color, but it will not print anything.
You can also check this:

```
echo -e 'hello \x1b[Byou'
```

and you'll see that the special sequence `\x1b[B` is interpreted by the terminal as "move the cursor down by one".

That's why your `echo $key` won't show something directly visible on the terminal, except for some blank lines.

—
<sup>1. I'm not sure why `grep` happens to print just `[B`, I have some different result on my setup.</sup>

Comment: To obtain expected results, it might be a good thing to `reset` a terminal before experimenting with escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

The terminal does not respond to key codes. Those are normally seen and interpreted by the application. They application may send a `cup` (cursor up), or down sequence (usually using the ncurses library).