# How tp Print/echo arrow character (not key) in unix - bash, version 3.2.52

Tags: bash, escape-characters, special-characters

How do I print `↑` and `↓` in Unix?

I have a script written in `bash` and I am printing some numbers with whom I want to print arrow keys to show increase/decrease. How do I literally print these arrow keys (let's say I assign them to some variable and print these along with my numbers) with my numbers using `echo` or `printf` in my shell script?

Using below [link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ReadingFunctionKeysInBash) I tried:

```
echo -e '\x1b\x5b\x35\x7e'
```

but it does not print anything. I can't find how to print arrow keys in [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19331/trying-to-print-up-down-arrow-keys).

Comment: What's wrong with `printf '↑'`?

Comment: Not Sure ..but how to get ↑ there in my unix m/c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `bash` 4.2 and above (or `ksh`, `mksh`, `pdksh`, `lksh`, `zsh`), you can use [ANSI C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

```
echo $'\U2191'
```

or setting locale with unicode characters:

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 printf '\U2191\n'
```

or you can use `perl` instead:

```
perl -CS -le 'print "\x{2191}"'
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
echo $'\U2191'
(
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
printf '\U2191\n'
)
Output:
hello
\U2191
\U2191
..Am i doing anything wrong

Comment: What is your bash version?

Comment: version 3.2.52 .

Comment: @user1107108: It only work with `bash` 4.2 and above.

Comment: â
...is printed with perl ...is it that my terminal does not support it at all

Comment: @user1107108: Does `echo -ne '\xe2\x86\x91'` work?

Comment: prints â ... i think there is no way..i tried saving a text file with an arrow in UTF-8 format ..transferred it to unix m/c ..it prints weird chars ï»¿â when i do cat ...and \357\273\277\342\206\221 when i do vi to it.

Comment: @user1107108: What terminal and ssh client did you use?

Comment: i am using ...putty

Comment: @user1107108: You can try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/393834/how-to-configure-putty-to-display-these-characters).

Comment: i think it is becoming an overkill now ... i will survive with + and - instead of arrows :-) ...plus even if my change of putty settings and make it work ..it is not guaranteed that it will print same way on other peoples consoles :-(

Answer (score 3):

Go to the unicode table: http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/, pick up the arrow you like, and then print it with the appropriate code preceded by `\u`:

```
echo -e "\u2191"
```

or even better use `printf`:

```
printf "\u2191\n"
```

Comment: both above just prints -    \u2191

Comment: @user1107108 What happens when you just copy with mouse the ↑ character and paste it into terminal?

Comment: it converts it to a . (dot)